# Is "The Melancholy of Momoneko-sama" based on any legends?

Tags: tamayura

The first half of episode 9 of Tamayura: Hitotose is a short fable-like story, "The Melancholy of Momoneko-sama" (*"Momoneko-sama no Yūutsu, na no de"*). It follows Momoneko, the strange pink cat in the series, and his battle with a boar.

[image]

Many anime fables are based on real Japanese legends. Is there any such basis for this one?